# fullcalendar js timezone offset issue

Tags: timezone, fullcalendar, timezone-offset

I'm using fullcalendar with timezone option set to to `local`. One of events fetched from server looks file follows.

```
{
    allDay: true
    className: "term"
    end: 1425949200000
    id: "5519341d300416ba3b825a65"
    rendering: "background"
    start: 1424629800000
    title: "Term 1"
}
```

the **end** date when converted to a date object is *Tue Mar 10 2015 06:30:00 GMT+0530 (IST)*. But the calendar when rendered shows the event only till 9th of March. I'm not sure whether it is visible in screenshot since it is a background event(light colour). I'm accessing from the same timezone so what is happening here?

[image: Calendar rendered]